# JavaFx GUI user input

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a simple Java programme that runs a text based game. The user inputs commands to the console in order to play the game, a scanner then reads the input. I have built a GUI but how can I use this to submit user input the the console and execute the command

cheers

Comment: The use of text fields in JavaFX is explained perfectly on the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/text-field.htm). Without seeing some code of an attempt you have made; I don't think people will respond or know what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are doing it programmatically (you can take a look to FXML GUI designing with SceneBuilder, as it will make your GUI design process easiear as it provides graphical GUI creation). You have several tutorials and step by step examples that will guide you searching google. You can do it programmatically as follows:

```
final TextField userText = new TextField();
somePanel.add(userText); //attach the text field to the scene.
final Button b = new Button();
somePanel.add(b); // attach the button to desired node in the scene
b.setOnAction(event -> {
    // Here you call the method with the desired logic, 
    // i suppose you have a text field where the user writes his input, in this case caled userText
    String text = userText.getText();
    // from here you have the text and you are able to use your scanner logic
});
```

Hopes this helps